# Debian: deb command not found. How can i fix it?

Tags: linux, debian, deb

I am trying to install graphics card Nvidia Geforce 660 on my desktop. Os: debian 8.

Here is the wiki which gives guidelines : https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#jessie-304xx

But as soon as I am on the first step:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

bash: deb: command not found
```

How can I install deb?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The instruction is

> Add "contrib" and "non-free" components to /etc/apt/sources.list, for example

I.e., you're supposed to add that line to the given file with a text editor. You are not supposed to execute it on a command line.

You can also install the **software-properties-common** package:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Afterwhich you can run the command below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free"
```

You can confirm that the repository was added to the list of repositories using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: you mean I need to add this
"deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free"
line at end of sources.list file?

Comment: @shunya yes, that's right.